# OA min/max input offset voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, input-offset-voltage

I want to build an instrumentation amplifier using MC33079 quad op amp, in page 3 of the [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/mc33078.pdf) it specified min and max input offset voltage:
[image]

- What causes the input offset voltage to increase?

Comment: Very slight differences between the temperature characteristics of the two input transistors.

Comment: @Andyaka So is it just temperature?

Comment: Yes, just temperature and a little bit of aging. Across the whole common mode input range it may be greater and, at those extremes of offset error, the gradient of change versus temperature may be greater. Better op-amps are specified this way to give the designer a better picture of worst case scenarios.

Comment: It may also be due to variation at fab, as well as temperature.  Small differences between the transistors when it was printed could lead to different voltages.  While they have good control of the fab and expected to see control of the differences such that the IOV < 0.15, there could be some devices up to 2,3 mV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the datasheet schematic:

[image]

You can see a number of things that could cause the offset voltage to change with temperature or with gradients across the die. Vbe of the transistors Q3/Q5 is the big one, but changes in the resistor values with temperature or time or even physical stress on the die could also have effects.

The typical drift (TCvos) of this amplifier is 2uV/°C over the -40°C to 85°C. Generally speaking, an amplifier with a high initial Vos will drift more than one that happens to be matched more closely out of the tube.

These days, if you need low Vos/TCVos you should specify an amplifier with guaranteed specifications that meet your requirements in that department.

Comment: Thanks, is 2uV/°C for input offset voltage temperature coefficient too high? for building an "home-brew" in-amp what other parameters are important to look for other than input offset voltage?

Comment: It's pretty horrible for some applications, for others it's negligible. I would say input bias current, noise, gain-bandwidth product are all important, as are power consumption, supply voltage range, output drive capability and so on. This particular old chip, if it has much in the way of innate talents would be fairly low **typical** noise and moderate frequency response. There's no guarantee on noise and I know for a fact that some samples have much higher than typical noise.